# Group different field by quarter

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got a aggregation :

```
{
        $group: {
          _id: "$_id",
          cuid: {$first: "$cuid"},           
          uniqueConnexion: {
            $addToSet: "$uniqueConnexion"
          },
          uniqueFundraisings: {
            $addToSet: "$uniqueFundraisings"
          }           
        }
    },
```

that result with :

```
{ 
"cuid" : "cjcqe7qdo00nl0ltitkxdw8r6", 
"uniqueConnexion" : [
    "09.2019", 
    "06.2019", 
    "07.2019", 
    "08.2019", 
    "05.2019"
], 
"uniqueFundraisings" : [
    "06.2019", 
    "02.2019", 
    "01.2019", 
    "03.2019", 
    "09.2018", 
    "10.2018"
],
}
```

And now I'm want to group the uniquerConnexion and uniqueFundraisings fields to a new field (name uniqueAction) and convert them to a quarter format.
So an output like this :

```
{ 
"cuid" : "cjcqe7qdo00nl0ltitkxdw8r6", 
"uniqueAction" : [
    "Q4-2018", 
    "Q1-2019",
    "Q2-2019",
    "Q3-2014",
], 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer shows the power of `$setUnion` operating on two lists.  I have taken that and expanded a little more to get the OP target state.  Given an input that more clearly shows some quarterly grouping (hint!):

```
var r =
{
    "cuid" : "cjcqe7qdo00nl0ltitkxdw8r6",
    "uniqueConnexion" : [
                         "01.2018",
                         "02.2018",
                         "08.2018",
                         "09.2018",
                         "10.2018",
                         "11.2018"
                         ],
    "uniqueFundraisings" : [
                         "01.2018",
                         "02.2018",
                         "05.2018",
                         "06.2018",
                         "12.2018"
                            ],
};
```

this agg:

```
db.foo.aggregate([

// Unique-ify the two lists:                                                          
{ $project: {
        cuid:1,
        X: { $setUnion: [ "$uniqueConnexion", "$uniqueFundraisings" ] } 
    }}

// Now need to get to quarters....                                                    
// The input date is "MM.YYYY".  Need to turn it into "Qn-YYYY":                      
,{ $project: {
  X: {$map: {
        input: "$X",
        as: "z",
        in: {$let: {
                    vars: { q: {$toInt: {$substr: ["$$z",0,2] }}},
                    in: {$concat: [{$cond: [
{$lte: ["$$q", 3]}, "Q1", {$cond: [
  {$lte: ["$$q", 6]}, "Q2", {$cond: [
{$lte: ["$$q", 9]}, "Q3", "Q4"] }
                                   ]}
                                                 ]} ,
                                    "-", {$substr:["$$z",3,4]},
                                ]}
                    }}}}}}

,{ $unwind: "$X"}
,{ $group: {_id: "$X", n: {$sum:1} }}

                      ]);
```

produces this output.  Yes, the OP was not looking for the count of things appearing in each quarter but very often that quickly follows on the heels of the original ask.

```
{ "_id" : "Q4-2018", "n" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Q3-2018", "n" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Q2-2018", "n" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Q1-2018", "n" : 2 }
```

Comment: It seems nice, but do you have an alternative with mongodb 3.6 ? So without $toInt

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

```
{ $project: { 
     cuid:1, 
     uniqueAction: { $setUnion: [ "$uniqueConnexio", "$uniqueAction" ] }, _id: 0 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Yes thanks, really helping ! Now need to group by quarter but I've got my ideas